# How can you save variables and load them after the program is closed?

Tags: python, pygame, save, load

I am creating a game and I have found out so far the most common save program, pickle, can only save/load while the program is on. The game I am making would take a long time to complete, and I don't think people would like to restart the game every time they quit. Is there a program I can import/download to save the variables elsewhere so they can be loaded again?

Comment: [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: *"can only save/load while the program is on"* - This is equivalent to saying Word isn't good enough because you can't load or save a file when your computer is off. Like everything, pickle will save to a file. The file isn't going to disappear when you close the program.

Answer (score 2):

> pickle, can only save/load while the program is on

I don't know what you mean by this.

In the strictest sense, it's true -- a program can't do *anything* if it's not running!

But it seems like you meant that a file saved with pickle would vanish when the program quits, and that is certainly not true.

Pickle is a perfectly reasonable way to save the game progress between play sessions.  Save the file before quitting, load the file on the next startup, boom you're back where you left off.

Comment: let me get a little more specific. When you setup up pickle on a program, and initiate the action of saving(temporarly in my case, pressing "s") it will save the variables requested as determined by the save code. when(in my case, the "l" key) you do the loading action, it will load the varibles right back up how you save them.  It works fine. Until the program is closed. If you try to load after launching the program agin, it wont. It will throw out an error bascically saying there is nothing to load, even though you saved it earlier. Im looking for a way around this so it can load up proprly

Comment: Show us that code.  You have a mistake in it somewhere.

Comment: # saving
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump([x1], f, protocol=2)

# loading
with open('savefile.dat', 'rb') as f:
    [x1] = pickle.load(f

Comment: What error do you get?  Also why are you putting brackets around `[x1]`?

Comment: [x1] = pickle.load(f)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: That error is because you're using brackets around x1.  It's nothing to do with pickle.  What is the purpose of the brackets?

Comment: the error is not of the brackets. Removed them and the exact same thing happened

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  Can you post some short sample code that has this error?

Comment: it must be somthing with my game. I made a sample and tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: i have fixed the issue. I'm not sure why but the variables must be defined as 0 or else pickle wont read them. Thanks for helping!